# How to transform a mongodb 3.4 collection by applying rules from another collection?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to derive documents from a collection after applying some rules from another collection.

I'm looking for the exact aggregation query to do this kind of operation in a fast way.

Rules are there to transform the following `stats` collection, according to some rules defined in the `rules` collection. `Rules` and `stats` are everchanging, so, I need to get the fresh results when I do the querying.

**For example:**

```
// collection to be transformed by the rules collection
stats = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    ratio: 3.0
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    ratio: 0.5
  }
]

// rules for how to transform the stats collection
rules = [
  {
    coll: 'stats',  // apply the rule to stats collection
    source: '_id',  // match the _id field in the stats collection
    eq: 1,          // apply only when stats._id == 1
    ratio: 2.0      // multiply the ratio of stats for the matched docs
  },
  {
    coll: 'stats',
    source: '_id',
    eq: 2,
    disable: true   // omit stats._id == 2 from the output
  }
]
```

So, if I apply rules onto stats, I should get this after aggregation for example:

```
stats = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    ratio: 6.0
  }
]

// 1st rule multiplied the 1st document of stats with 2.0
// 2nd rule disabled fetching the 2nd document of stats
```

*Stats collection has hundreds of thousands of documents, and Rules collection has thousands of documents*.

I looked into aggregation framework for this, looks like it can be done with it. Or, I'd need to apply rules from my application code, one by one to derive the result I wanted, but this could be slow.

See also [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/351024/deriving-data-from-mongodb-collections-that-are-distinct-for-each-website) in stack exchange software engineering.

Comment: No idea what you are talking about. What are rules? What are you expecting to happen? You need to be a lot more specific with examples of what you expect.

Comment: Updated the post. I gave the input and output examples, what else do you need? I can edit it.

Comment: It's still really obtuse and being honest you didn't update much. Are you at least able to use a latest MongoDB 3,4? We can have ["views"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/)  if you can. There are limitations to this though, so it depends on how you need to use it.

Comment: OK, I updated it again. Yes, it's Mongo 3.4.4. I looked also to `views`, I still need the aggregation query for this operation.

Comment: This is why you need to be a lot more specific in your question. If you want input, you need really cover all the things that need to happen. Probably even break that up into several questions to be frank about it.

Comment: There are two collections, and `stats` coll needs to be transformed by the rules inside `rules` coll. I don't know how I can be more clear :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the screenshot below, this aggregation framework query gives your desired result:

```
db.mystats.aggregate([
   {$lookup:
     {
       from: "rules",
       localField: "_id",
       foreignField: "eq",
       as: "docs"
     }
   },
   {$unwind:"$docs"},
   {$match: 
     { "docs.disable":{ "$exists": false}}
   },
   {$project: 
     {
        "_id":"$_id", 
        "ratio": { $multiply: [ "$ratio", "$docs.ratio" ] }
     }
    }
]
)
```

Here the output of the query execution on the input example you provided:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you!